# Zone and Jquery issue in Tapestry5.2.6

Tags: tapestry, zone

I am migrating my web application from tapestry version 5.1.0 to 5.2.6. I am using jquery dialog to handle popped out display (instead of a pop-up window).

While using tapestry v5.1.0, I used jquery js (version 1.6.2) library with tapestry standard js library (prototype n other js) with no discrepancy. 
But now, when I have migrated to tapestry v5.2.6, there are conflicts in the javascripts. If I comment out jquery js import in a page, zone works i.e. gets updated but dialog doesn’t work and if  I include jquery js in the page, the dialog works perfectly, but it shows error for zone updation event  saying “Element 'selectZone' does not have an associated Tapestry.ZoneManager object.”

So basically, I need to use both jQuery and prototype js together in the page for tapestry v5.2.6. Please suggest a way for the same.

Regards,
Mahendra

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include [JQuery in "no conflict" mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) so that it doesn't butt-heads with prototypejs.

Otherwise you might want to consider using [tapestry5-jquery](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/) to eliminate prototypejs altogether. I prefer the prototypejs implementation (one reason being the tapestry code is tidier) but this is an option many users prefer.